# Function for colision detection always returns true

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I am probably missing something really simple but I do not understand why this function always returns true and logs the two objects even when they are not near one another. 
My code:

```
var collideRect=function(obj1, obj2){
   var x1=obj1.x,y1=obj1.y,x2=obj2.x, y2=obj2.y;
   var b1=obj1.breadth,h1=obj1.height;
   var b2=obj2.breadth,h2=obj2.height;
   var xCollide, yCollide;
// determine if the x values are closer than half the breadth of each rectangle to each other
   if(x1+b1/2>x2-b2/2||x1-b1/2<x2+b2/2){xCollide=true};
// determine if the y values are closer than half their heights from one another 
   if(y1+h1/2>y2-h2/2||y1-h1/2<y2+h2/2){yCollide=true};
   if(xCollide&&yCollide){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)+".   "+JSON.stringify(obj2)) ;
    return true;
   }; 
}
```

None of the values are ever0. The function takes to objects each with properties: 
breadth,
height,
x,
y.
These are all positive numbers. I have checked the order of operations of each of statement and they are all fine.

Comment: This question is too unclear and unverifiable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help try and fix your question

Comment: It could possibly be those if statements. Remember PEMDAS/BODMAS from Mathematics? In your if statements x1 + b1 / 2  for example will do b1 / 2 + x1 because there are no parenthesis. Division comes before addition.

Comment: The order of operations is fine

Comment: Deckerz, I believe everything needed I've posted, if you need more info please specify and I'll post it

Comment: @user7951676 We can't guess what we need from what you've posted. Your question is unclear and you're asking us to guess what your problem is. It could be that you're trying to divide by zero, it could be order of operations, it could be that you're using an OR statement which will always evaluate to true because you're saying if(condition 1 is greater than condition 2 or condition 1 is less than condition 2, xcollide = true. Take your pick.

Comment: Can I ask what are the objects involved in your collision algo? what's the scenario? and how this behave?

Comment: Edited to give more context

Comment: Also provide the value of `obj1 and obj2`

Comment: Do you need an explicit `return false` after  closing `if(xCollide&&yCollide){` ?

Comment: No, a function returns undefined if no explicit return statement is made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statements are incorrect. See below for adjusted algorithm and basic console assertions.

Essentially you need to detect if there's no space between any of the edges. If there is no space you know a collision has occurred.

A break down is as follows:

Step1.

Check the left edge of rectangle1.

If the left edge of rectangle1 is less than the right edge of rectangle2 (x2 + b2) there may be an intersection of the left side of rectangle1 and the right side of rectangle2.

Step2.

Check the right side of rectangle1.

If the right side of rectangle1 is greater than the left side of rectangle2, rectangle1 intersects with rectangle2 at the left side of rectangle2. We detect that both of these conditions are true using && to ensure that a collision has occurred.

We do the exact same checks for the y coordinates of both rectangles to achieve detect whether the rectangles intersect on the y plane..

```js
var collideRect = function (obj1, obj2) {
 var collision = false;

 var x1 = obj1.x,
 y1 = obj1.y,
 x2 = obj2.x,
 y2 = obj2.y;

 var b1 = obj1.breadth,
 h1 = obj1.height;

 var b2 = obj2.breadth,
 h2 = obj2.height;

 var xCollide,
 yCollide;
        // if left edge of rect1 is left of the left edge of rect2 plus its 
        // width AND left edge of rect1 plus rect1's width is greater than 
        // the left edge of rect2, we have an x-coordinate collision.
        // if either set of conditions is false, the rects don't overlap.
 if (x1 < x2 + b2 && x1 + b1 > x2) {
  xCollide = true;
 }
    // same as the x check but on the y plane
 if (y1 < y2 + h2 && h1 + y1 > y2) {
  yCollide = true;
 }

 if (xCollide && yCollide) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) + ".   " + JSON.stringify(obj2));
  collision = true;
 }
 return collision;
}

// test
var rect1 = {
 x: 5,
 y: 5,
 breadth: 50,
 height: 50
};
var rect2 = {
 x: 20,
 y: 10,
 breadth: 10,
 height: 10
};

console.assert(collideRect(rect1, rect2) === true); // collision

var rect3 = {
 x: 55,
 y: 55,
 breadth: 50,
 height: 50
};
var rect4 = {
 x: 20,
 y: 10,
 breadth: 10,
 height: 10
};

console.assert(collideRect(rect3, rect4) === false); // no collision
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works, if the rectangles are equal size I understand however why does it work for different sized rectangles

Comment: It checks the coordinate positions and uses the width and height of each as an offset. if either of these sets of numbers intersects (lands in the same range) it detects a collision. I'll update the answer with a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I understand much better now, out of interest is there many other basic algorithms for detecting colisions between other shapes or shapes at different angles?

Comment: Yeah, the method you're using is called an axis aligned bounding box. There's also circle collision and there's the separating axis theorem. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection for some basics. You can also do sprite based collision by XORing pixels using bitwise math, though only useful for grey scale.

Comment: Sorry, I just got this result which is wrong: {"x":35,"y":38.39000000000001,"vx":0,"vy":-0.6599999999999997,"ay":0.005,"height":10,"breadth":10,"lives":1,"aim":"up"}.   {"x":35.79999999999909,"y":86,"breadth":15,"height":10,"lives":1,"id":"enemy139"}, canvas.js:32 collideRect()

Comment: Yeah I have a circle one that calculates the distance between the centres than companies that with the sum of the radio

Comment: @user7951676 My example had an error in, the height if calculation was y1 < y2 + h2 && h1 + y1 > h2 I changed it to y1 < y2 + h2 &&  h1 + y1 > y2. I updated the answer to reflect that change. My bad :)

Comment: Thank you, your help is appreciated